# Cómo acceder a un array almacenado en un objeto que se pasa desde javascript a PHP

Tags: php, javascript, json, array

estoy pasando un json desde javascript a PHP que contiene varios valores, entre ellos un array. En PHP puedo acceder a las variables excepto al array:

Codigo Javascript:

```
var datos = {"id": id,
         "name":$("#inputName").val(),
         "address" : $("#inputAddress").val(),
         "phone" : $("#inputPhone").val(),
         "email" : $("#inputEmail").val()};

var tarifa = [{"tarifa": $("#inputRateName").val()},
          {"price": $("#inputRatePrice").val()},
          {"coin": $("#listCoin").children(":selected").val()}
];
datos['tarifa'] = JSON.stringify(tarifa);
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: datos,
  url: 'archivo.php',
  success: function(data) {
      alert('OK');
  },
  error: function(e, msg) {
      alert("error: " + e);
      return false;
  }
});
return false;
```

Codigo en PHP:

```
//Puedo acceder a los valores de id, name, address, phone y email asi:
$direccion = $_POST['address'];

//Pero no puedo acceder a la tarifa. He probado estas opciones:
$tarifa = json_decode($_POST(['tarifa']), true);
$tarifa = json_decode($_REQUEST(['tarifa']), true);
$tarifa = $_POST(['tarifa'];
```

¿Cual sería la forma correcta de acceder al array? Gracias.

Comment: ¿Has probado quitándole los parentésis al POST? → `$_POST['tarifa']`

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres lograr con ese array?¿Quieres almacenar los datos de una tarifa?

Comment: Necesito acceder al array para guardar los valores en una tabla en la base de datos.

Comment: Cada elemento del array, tal cual lo tienes, es un par clave valor, ¿no sería mejor que cada elemento fuese una `tarifa1,tarifa2,etc` y cada tarifa tuviese esos pares clave valor? Porque si lo que intentas es guardar un registro de los datos de una tarifa, no se si de esa forma será correcto hacerlo

Comment: Muchas gracias @G3I0, he modificado los elementos del array y ya puedo guardar su valor.

Comment: Te pongo el comentario como respuesta para que puedas validar la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posiblemente la mejor solución sea agregar los datos que quieres tener en tu PHP a los datos que envías encapsulándolos en un objeto, y no un array de objetos (te facilitará acceder a ellos una vez en PHP):

```
var tarifa = {
  "tarifa": $("#inputRateName").val(),
  "price": $("#inputRatePrice").val(),
  "coin": $("#listCoin").children(":selected").val()
};
```

Aún así al final te proporciono la solución con el mismo tipo de dato que has propuesto.

Por otro lado, no es necesario usar `JSON.stringify` para agregar datos a los ya existentes. Basta con añadirlos a los datos que van a ser enviados tal cual, y serán recibidos por el PHP de manera más sencilla y sin tener que usar `json_decode` ni trucos de ningún tipo.

```
/* Generamos los datos iniciales */
var datos = {
  "id": id,
  "name":$("#inputName").val(),
  "address" : $("#inputAddress").val(),
  "phone" : $("#inputPhone").val(),
  "email" : $("#inputEmail").val(),
  "tarifa" : tarifa
};
/* Generamos la variable "tarifa", pero como objeto directamente */
var tarifa = {
  "tarifa": $("#inputRateName").val(),
  "price": $("#inputRatePrice").val(),
  "coin": $("#listCoin").children(":selected").val()
};
/* Los agregamos a los datos, pero sin usar JSON.stringify */
datos['tarifa'] = tarifa;
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: datos,
  url: 'formulario.php',
  success: function(data) {
    alert('OK');
  },
  error: function(e, msg) {
    alert("error: " + e);
    return false;
  }
});
```

La parte receptora en PHP se quedaría:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['tarifa'])) {
    /* Ahora todo se encuentra directamente bajo $_POST['tarifa'] */
    echo "Tarifa: " . htmlspecialchars($_POST['tarifa']['tarifa']);
    echo "Price: " . htmlspecialchars($_POST['tarifa']['price']);
    echo "Coin: " . htmlspecialchars($_POST['tarifa']['coin']);
    die(var_export($_POST));
}
```

---

Sin cambiar la estructura de los datos de "tarifas" también se pueden obtener los datos fácilmente, pero de manera diferente:

```
/* Generamos los datos iniciales */
var datos = {
  "id": id,
  "name":$("#inputName").val(),
  "address" : $("#inputAddress").val(),
  "phone" : $("#inputPhone").val(),
  "email" : $("#inputEmail").val(),
  "tarifa" : tarifa
};
/* Generamos la variable "tarifa", pero como antes (no recomendado) */
var tarifa = [
  {"tarifa": $("#inputRateName").val()},
  {"price": $("#inputRatePrice").val()},
  {"coin": $("#listCoin").children(":selected").val()}
];
/* Los agregamos a los datos, pero sin usar JSON.stringify */
datos['tarifa'] = tarifa;
```

Ahora los datos están disponibles en:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['tarifa'])) {
    /* Ahora todo se encuentra directamente bajo $_POST['tarifa'] */
    echo "Tarifa: " . htmlspecialchars($_POST['tarifa'][0]['tarifa']);
    echo "Price: " . htmlspecialchars($_POST['tarifa'][1]['price']);
    echo "Coin: " . htmlspecialchars($_POST['tarifa'][2]['coin']);
    die(var_export($_POST));
}
```

Como puede observarse es más cómodo el método recomendado anteriormente.